# Why are the spherical and cartesian galactic coordinates in the ATNF Pulsar Catalogue different?

Tags: coordinate, data-analysis, pulsar

I am trying to relate Galactic Latitude (b) and Longitude (l) (spherical coordinates) to galactic cartesian x,y,z coordinates in the ATNF pulsar catalog.

[This query](http://www.atnf.csiro.au/people/pulsar/psrcat/proc_form.php?version=1.58&Name=Name&GL=GL&GB=GB&ZZ=ZZ&XX=XX&YY=YY&startUserDefined=true&c1_val=&c2_val=&c3_val=&c4_val=&sort_attr=jname&sort_order=asc&condition=&pulsar_names=&ephemeris=short&coords_unit=raj%2Fdecj&radius=&coords_1=&coords_2=&style=Long%20with%20last%20digit%20error&no_value=*&fsize=3&x_axis=&x_scale=linear&y_axis=&y_scale=linear&state=query&table_bottom.x=43&table_bottom.y=24) shows some sample data with `G_l`, `G_b`, `XX`, `YY`, and `ZZ`; excerpt:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
#     NAME                     Gl     Gb     ZZ     XX     YY
                               (deg)  (deg)  (kpc)  (kpc)  (kpc)
------------------------------------------------------------------
1     J0002+6216    cwp+17     117.33 -0.07  -0.00  0.00   8.50
2     J0006+1834    cnt96      108.17 -42.98 -0.59  0.60   8.70
3     J0007+7303    aaa+09c    119.66 10.46  0.25   1.20   9.18
```

The description of the variables from the [ATNF documentation](http://www.atnf.csiro.au/research/pulsar/psrcat/psrcat_help.html?type=normal&highlight=gl#gl) are as follows:

```
GL:          Galactic longitude (degrees) 
GB:          Galactic latitude (degrees) 
[...]
ZZ:          Distance from the Galactic plane, based on Dist
XX:          X-Distance in X-Y-Z Galactic coordinate system (kpc)
YY:          Y-Distance in X-Y-Z Galactic coordinate system (kpc)
```

My understanding is that these variables should be related by the following equations:

- `tan(G_L) = YY/XX`
- `tan(G_b) = XX/ZZ`

However, when I test this assumption my calculated values are very different:

[image: test-spreadsheet]

I have tried exploring the possibility that the x,y,z coordinate system may be oriented differently than I expect, but I can find no orientation that yields similar results for `G_l` or `G_b`:

[image: trig-exaustive-search]

Where could I have gone wrong? I feel like I am losing my mind not being able to convert these with simple trig.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ATNF Pulsar Catalogue's galactic longitude and latitude are heliocentric,
but the origin of their rectangular coordinates is near the center of our galaxy.

The [catalogue documentation](http://www.atnf.csiro.au/people/pulsar/psrcat/psrcat_help.html),
section 6. Distances, says:

> The Galactocentric coordinate system (XX, YY, ZZ) is right-handed
>   with the Sun at (0.0, 8.5 kpc, 0.0)
>   and the ZZ axis directed toward the north Galactic pole.

From a heliocentric point of view
[(U, V, W)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_coordinate_system#Rectangular_coordinates)
= (8.5 - YY, XX, ZZ).
Then $\tan{l} = V / U$ and $\tan{b} = W / \sqrt{U^2 + V^2}$
as you'd expect.

Comment: Aha, thank you! A few notes in case anyone runs into similar troubles:

1. my YY and XX column labels are swapped (oops).
2. This answer unconventionally maps yxz to uvw, more typically it is xyz to uvw
3. The last equation for `G_b` should be `tan(b) = 90 - W/sqrt(u^2+v^2)`